# How to leave only one defined sub-string in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace

Say I have one of the strings:

```
"a b c d e f f g" || "a b c f d e f g"
```

And I want there to be only one occurrence of a substring (**f** in this instance) throughout the string so that it is somewhat sanitized.
The result of each string would be:

```
"a b c d e f g" || "a b c d e f g"
```

An example of the use would be:

```py
str = "a b c d e f g g g g g h i j k l"
str.leaveOne("g") 
#// a b c d e f g h i j k l
```

Comment: Why are you passing "f" to `str.leaveOne` but it is removing `g`s?

Comment: So which occurance you want to omit?

Comment: @MarkMeyer appologies, I fixed the question.

Comment: So only the last of the duplicates are kept?

Comment: In a way @Chris it splits by the letter, then removes all the empty pieces for (n-1) of them and replaces the last of the n sequence with the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't matter which instance you leave, you can use `str.replace`, which takes a parameter signifying the number of replacements you want to perform:

```
def leave_one_last(source, to_remove):
    return source.replace(to_remove, '', source.count(to_remove) - 1)
```

This will leave the *last* occurrence.

We can modify it to leave the *first* occurrence by reversing the string twice:

```
def leave_one_first(source, to_remove):
    return source[::-1].replace(to_remove, '', source.count(to_remove) - 1)[::-1]
```

However, that is ugly, not to mention inefficient. A more elegant way might be to take the substring that ends with the first occurrence of the character to find, replace occurrences of it in the rest, and finally concatenate them together:

```
def leave_one_first_v2(source, to_remove):
    first_index = source.index(to_remove) + 1
    return source[:first_index] + source[first_index:].replace(to_remove, '')
```

If we try this:

```
string = "a b c d e f g g g g g h i j k l g"

print(leave_one_last(string, 'g'))
print(leave_one_first(string, 'g'))
print(leave_one_first_v2(string, 'g'))
```

Output:

```
a b c d e f      h i j k l g
a b c d e f g     h i j k l 
a b c d e f g     h i j k l
```

If you don't want to keep spaces, then you should use a version based on `split`:

```
def leave_one_split(source, to_remove):
    chars = source.split()
    first_index = chars.index(to_remove) + 1
    return ' '.join(chars[:first_index] + [char for char in chars[first_index:] if char != to_remove])

string = "a b c d e f g g g g g h i j k l g"

print(leave_one_split(string, 'g'))
```

Output:

```
'a b c d e f g h i j k l'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just use a regex and `re.sub` to look for groups of two or more of your letter with or without a space and replace it by a single instance:

```
import re
def leaveOne(s, char):  
    return re.sub(r'((%s\s?)){2,}' % char, r'\1' , s)

leaveOne("a b c d e f g g g h i j k l", 'g') 
# 'a b c d e f g h i j k l'

leaveOne("a b c d e f ggg h i j k l", 'g')
# 'a b c d e f g h i j k l'

leaveOne("a b c d e f g h i j k l", 'g')
# 'a b c d e f g h i j k l'
```

**EDIT**

If the goal is to get rid of *all* occurrences of the letter except one, you can still use a regex with a lookahead to select all letters followed by the same:

```
import re
def leaveOne(s, char):  
    return re.sub(r'(%s)\s?(?=.*?\1)' % char, '' , s)

print(leaveOne("a b c d e f g g g h i j k l g", 'g'))
# 'a b c d e f h i j k l g'

print(leaveOne("a b c d e f ggg h i j k l gg g", 'g'))
# 'a b c d e f h i j k l g'

print(leaveOne("a b c d e f g h i j k l", 'g'))
# 'a b c d e f g h i j k l'
```

This should even work with more complicated patterns like:

```
leaveOne("a b c ffff d e ff g", 'ff')
# 'a b c d e ff g'
```

Comment: This won't work in case of `leaveOne("a b c f d e f g", 'f')` > `'a b c f d e f g'`, where duplicates are not adjacent

Comment: I think I read the question differently that you @Chris. That looks like the correct result to me. It gets rid of substrings of multiple `f`s. There aren't any in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Given String

```
mystr = 'defghhabbbczasdvakfafj'

cache = {}

seq = 0
for i in mystr:
    if i not in cache:
        cache[i] = seq
        print (cache[i])
        seq+=1

mylist = []
```

Here I have ordered the dictionary with values

```
 for key,value in sorted(cache.items(),key=lambda x : x[1]):
        mylist.append(key)
 print ("".join(mylist))
```